# What is the meaning of the parameters in the axis-angle exponential representation of $\rm SO(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, rotation

In the axis-angle parametrization, an element of the rotation group $\rm SO(3)$ is written as
$$R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)=\exp\left[-i(\vec{J}\cdot\hat{n})\theta\right]$$
where $\theta$ represents the angle of rotation about the $\hat{n}$-axis. The interpretation of $\theta$ is very clear. However, with $$\hat{n}\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3),$$ when the *same* element is written as $$R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)=\exp\left[-i(J_1\theta_1+J_2\theta_2+J_3\theta_3)\right],$$ do the parameters $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ have any obvious and useful physical interpretation? It is clear that these are not Euler angles and therefore, knowing them (from the knowledge of $\hat{n}$ and $\theta$) does not help us to perform an equivalent sequence of Euler rotations.

Comment: Because the rotations around different axes do not commute, the individual components $\theta_{j}$ don't really have a direct physically meaning for a finite rotation.  For an infinitesimal rotation, the ordering of the of the rotations doesn't matter, so you can identify, say $\Delta\theta_{x}$ as the portion of the total rotation the represents a turn around the $x$-axis.

Comment: It’s called the axis-angle representation because the parameters are intended to be the axis and the angle.

Comment: @Buzz Is it possible to relate the parameters $\theta_i$'s to the Euler angles?

Comment: @Solidification Infintesimally, they *are* just the infinitesimal Euler angles:  $\Delta\vec{\theta}=(\beta,-\gamma,\alpha)$ for Wikipedia's paramterization of the Euler angles, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles